# Play stereo sound as mono sound for different channel using c#.net

Tags: c#, audio, avaudioplayer

I want to play a stereo sound in the following manner using c#.net

It’s a stereo track: Make it possible to hear only the L or only the R channel or both
channels simultaneously. If you play only on channel put the audio out in mono so that
you can hear the one channel in either speakers or headphones

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: user crosspost on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/141393/play-stereo-sound-as-mono-sound-for-different-channel-using-c-net

Comment: Somewhere i read that we can do this by VLC player.By select Audio-> Audio Channels -> Right or Left . But ,how can i do this via programming in c#. Is there anybody who can help me ??

Answer (score 2):

In [Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,overview.aspx) you need use [AudioCompressionManager.MergeStereo](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,samples.aspx#sample12) and AudioCompressionManager.SplitStereo methods

See pseudo code below

```
    AudioCompressionManager.SplitStereo(stereo, left, right);

    PlayerEx plex = new PlayexEx(); 
    plex.Done += new PlayerEx.DoneEventHandler(plex_Done);   
    plex.OpenPlayer(format);      
    plex.StartPlay();

    enum State {    Left,    Right,    Both }

    void plex_Done(object sender, DoneEventArgs e) {    
      byte[] left50ms = Cut(left, 50);    
      byte[] right50ms = Cut(right, 50);    
      switch (State)    {
        case State.Left:
          plex.AddData(AudioCompressionManager.MergeStereo(left50ms, left50ms));
        break;
        case State.Right:
          plex.AddData(AudioCompressionManager.MergeStereo(right50ms, right50ms));
        break;
        case State.Both:
          plex.AddData(AudioCompressionManager.MergeStereo(left50ms, right50ms));
        break; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this .

I have found a library named zLib . U can use this library for play audio,Mix channels and many others . This library is very usefull for sound related work and written in many languages like VC++,C#.Net,VB.Net etc. Goto the below link :

[zLib for Sound Work](http://libzplay.sourceforge.net/WELCOME.html)

This is a best library i have founded for sound.